# ansible.builtin.copy module - "Not a directory" error when copying contents

Tags: ansible

I have a task file that copies the contents of a variable to a file in a temp directory. It keeps throwing this error:

> Failed to get information on remote file (/tmp/ansible.in86oad1backup/awx_backup_2023-06-04.json): Not a directory

Here's the contents of the task file:

```yaml
---
- debug:
    msg: test
  register: awx_export

- name: Backup the AWX configuration
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    dest: "{{ backup_filepath }}.json"
    content: "{{ awx_export }}"
```

The task is pretty much exactly the same as the example in [Ansible's documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#examples):

```yaml
- name: Copy using inline content
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: '# This file was moved to /etc/other.conf'
    dest: /etc/mine.conf
```

So why is it throwing this error?

Comment: There's not enough debuging information in your question to answer. Meanwhile, the most obvious cause would be that the directory `/tmp/ansible.in86oad1backup/` where you try to copy your inline file does not exist on the target server.

Comment: @Zeitounator when I put more info people tell me to put the minimum reproducible example, when I put less people tell me I didn't put enough. can't win on this site.

Comment: Note that the phrase is "minimal *reproducible* example"; not just "minimal example". That means enough code + configuration that we can run it locally and reproduce the problem you're asking about. Without that local reproducer many questions are difficult to answer.

Comment: @jerdub1993 I guess people tell you there's too much when you add many information not strictly necessary/relevant to understand and reproduce your problem (e.g. your full log when only a few lines are necessary, an entire playbook when only one task fails on its own....) and that it is not enough when it is too sparse (which is the case here). As reported by larsks, you can refer to the [mre] page for more info on what is expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The path `/tmp/ansible.in86oad1backup` was created with the `ansible.builtin.tempfile` module. I had forgotten the `state: directory` parameter, so it was created as a file, not a directory.